# Offering a black/whitelist tab?

Tags: names

I am working on a project (browser extension) which will implement either black or whitelisting depending on the users choice.

However I want to contain the GUI elements that control this/these list/s under a tab. So am I  at a loss of what to name this tab, since it could be providing the interface for the Whitelist or Blacklist.

What should I name this tab?

[image]

Comment: In your place I used a small, but good visible (so 12px radius) circles, with red/gray/green color. And didn't give any list (or only deep hidden in the menu system). The user want to see, what is the current status of the actually viewed object.

Comment: What exactly determines if it will so WL/BL/Both? The content of the tab or user setting outside the tab?

Comment: @Izhaki Within the tab there will be the ability to set the mode of the extension to either only run on the defined URLs OR not run on the specifically defined URLs. I think actually providing the option exclusively makes sense, offering both would only be useful to preserve the list if they wanted to toggle between the two but I can't see that being used enough to be worth the effort.

Comment: "My filters" seems like a decent suggestion. Did your users have any alternatives?

Comment: @RedSirius we've not pushed this onto users yet, just within the developer circles we were unsure. It would be good if we could pick a single word, eg 'Filtering' but it seems vague.

Comment: All you really need is something good enough, and then adjust it if you get feedback. "Filter List" or its ilk seems fine, and it what we use on our application as it's exactly what those options did.

Comment: To be frank - can't think of anything better than white/blacklist.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with websites , I would just use the term **website exceptions** or **website filtering** or **website management** so that people know exactly what they will do in that tab. Here is an example of how [K9](http://www1.k9webprotection.com/) shows the different options to users

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you ask some actual users; you're bound to find the right *non-technical* words they use to refer to such functionality. Off the top of my head, "filters" or "permissions" comes to mind. "Blacklist" or "whitelist" is too technical for a general audience.

Comment: I actually think most people will be familiar with the term 'blacklist' - neither 'filters' nor 'permissions' are as descriptive.

Comment: Indeed, I actually tried `Filtering` but it wasn't well received which is why I've come here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that word choice is the asker's main issue.

***Blacklist***: implies people or things that are illegal or evil

***Block***: implies people or things that warrant exclusion but aren't illegal or evil

***Permission***: implies people or things that warrant exclusion but only because they aren't high enough in the user-access hierarchy

***Filter***: implies people or things that warrant exclusion but only because they aren't relevant to current goal/search